# .each .children() element with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, each, addclass

I build this scraping out the answers on stackoverflow. What i want to achive:

For each `.element` in `.element-wrapper` add the class  `.visible` with delay *1000ms* .

```
$('.element-wrapper').children('.element').each(function(i) {
  var $item = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.element').addClass('visible');
  }, 1000 * i);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you are almost right... Just change one line below to make it context sensitive to the current wrapper:

```
$('.element-wrapper').children('.element').each(function(i) {
  var $item = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $item.addClass('visible');  // Change this line.
  }, 1000 * i);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Praveen for looking over my code. the simplest things are sometimes unseen.

Comment: @Glockohnee That's totally true... :D